# When listing `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL`, I want an array of just the directory names, not the whole path. How do I do this?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` to get a listing of a particular directory. Is there a simple way to get just the directory names, rather than the full path?

For example, instead of:

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/.../Documents/MySavedFiles/1872399DDF
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/.../Documents/MySavedFiles/3431109ABE
```

I want just

```
1872399DDF
3431109ABE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert the NSURLs into NSStrings, and then you can extract the directory name.

Some very useful methods for NSString are lastPathComponent and stringByDeletingPathExtension

```
NSMutableArray* directoryNames = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray* fullPaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:...];

for (NSURL* url in fullPaths)
{
     [directoryNames addObject:[[url absoluteString] lastPathComponent]];
}
```

Comment: `NSURL` also has a `lastPathComponent` convenience method as of OS X 10.6/iOS 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *URLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:...];
NSArray *filenames = [URLs valueForKeyPath:@"lastPathComponent"];
```